# Non-homogeneous linear equation-simplification

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Question:

> Three solutions of a certain second order non-homogeneous linear equation are:
>
> $\psi_1(t)=t^2$
>
> $\psi_2(t)=t^2+e^{2t}$
>
> $\psi_3(t)=1+t^2+2e^{2t}$
>
> Find the general solution of this equation

There is a lemma in my book that says the difference of two solution is a solution to the homogeneous equation.

I applied that:

$\psi_1(t)-\psi_2(t)=t^2-t^2-e^{2t}=-e^{2t}$

and

$\psi_2(t)-\psi_3(t)=t^2+e^{2t}-1-t^2-2e^{2t}=-1-e^{2t}$

Since they are linearly independent, then they are solutions of the homogeneous equation and we have:

$ c_1(-e^{2t})+c_2(-1-e^{2t})$

$(1). y(t)= c_1(-e^{2t})+c_2(-1-e^{2t})+t^2$

However, I am having trouble cleaning this equation up and that is where I need help. My solution key says:

$(2). y(t)=c_1+c_2e^{2t}+t^2$

I understand $t^2$ is a particular solution and that $c_1$ and $c_2$ are coefficients but how did they clean up (1) to (2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "atoms" of the three solutions are $1$, $t^2$ and $e^{2t}$. Which means your homogeneous linear DE has as roots of the characteristic polynomial at least $\lambda=0$ with multiplicity $3$ and $λ=2$ once. The last implies that also $t$ is a solution and your general homogeneous solution is
$$
c_1+c_2t+c_3t^2+c_4e^{2t}
$$ 
for the ODE
$$
y^{(4)}-2y'''=0
$$

---

**Addendum:** The above was for the case of a homogeneous linear ODE. The task was about an inhomogeneous linear ODE. In that case you are nearly done with your own contemplations. You just need to collect the constants. Lets rename your constants to $d_{1,2}$, then equation (1) can be rewritten as
$$
y(t)=d_1(−e^{2t})+d_2(−1−e^{2t})+t^2=(-d_2)·1+(-d_1-d_2)·e^{2t} + t^2
$$
Thus making the linear bijective variable transform $c_1=-d_2$, $c_2=-d_1-d_2$, you find that formula (2) is essentially the same as formula (1).