# Find the general solution for this equation.

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Three solutions of a non-homogeneous second order linear equation are $$\psi _1(t)=1+e^{t^2}, \quad \psi _2(t)=1+te^{t^2} \quad \text{and} \quad \psi _3(t)=(t+1)e^{t^2}+1 $$
Find the general solution for this equation.

I'm not sure of how to find the general solution. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Does this help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209715/non-homogeneous-linear-equation-simplification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\psi _1(t)=1+e^{t^2}, \quad \psi _2(t)=1+te^{t^2} \quad \text{and} \quad \psi _3(t)=(t+1)e^{t^2}+1$$
You can deduce that these are also solutions to the DE:
$$  \psi _3(t)-\psi _2(t)=e^{t^2}$$
And
$$\psi _3(t)-\psi _1(t)=te^{t^2}, $$
The Wronskian gives:
$$W(e^{t^2},te^{t^2})=e^{2t^2} \ne 0$$
So the solution to the homogeneous equation is:
$$y_h=c_1e^{t^2}+c_2te^{t^2}$$